# A Gronwall-type inequality for $L^p$ norms

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Here is a problem from my homework, which asks me to show a Gronwall-type inequality.

> Let $1\leq\beta<\gamma\leq\infty, 0<T\leq\infty$ and let $f\in L^\rho(0,T)$, where $1\leq\rho<\infty$ is defined by $\frac1\rho=\frac1\beta-\frac1\gamma$. If $\eta\geq0$ and $\varphi\in L_{\text{loc}}^\gamma([0,T))$ satisfy
>   $$\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,t)}\leq\eta+\|f\varphi\|_{L^\beta(0,t)},$$
>   for all $0<t<T$. Prove that
>   $$\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,t)}\leq\eta\Phi(\|f\|_{L^\rho(0,t)}),$$
>   for all $0<t<T$, where $\Phi(s)=2\Gamma(3+2s)$ and $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.

I cannot see why the Gamma function appears here. Applying Hölder's inequality to the assumption gives that
$$\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,t)}\leq\eta+\|f\|_{L^\rho(0,t)}\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,t)}.$$
Now we can do the iteration, but this process fails to give the desired result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: there's no further context to the question?

Comment: @CalvinKhor No. I’m afraid the above is all that I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m grateful for all efforts people made to solve my problem. With the help of my teacher, I finally find a solution. And it turns out that there is some thing wrong in the original problem.

Let $0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=T$ be such that $\|f\|_{L^\rho(x_{k-1},x_k)}=1/2$ for each $1\leq k\leq n-1$ and $\|f\|_{L^\rho(x_{n-1},x_n)}\leq1/2$. A simple calculation gives that $\|f\|_{L^\rho(0,x_k)}=\frac{k^{1/\rho}}2$ for $1\leq k\leq n-1$.

Next we do the iteration. By Minkowski's inequality and Hölder's inequality
\begin{align*}
\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,x_{k+1})}&\leq\eta+\|f\varphi\|_{L^\beta(0,x_{k+1})}\\
&\leq\eta+\|f\varphi\|_{L^\beta(0,x_{k})}+\|f\varphi\|_{L^\beta(x_k,x_{k+1})}\\
&\leq\eta+\|f\|_{L^\rho(0,x_k)}\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,x_k)}+\|f\|_{L^\rho(x_k,x_{k+1})}\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(x_k,x_{k+1})}\\
&\leq\eta+\frac{k^{1/\rho}}2\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,x_k)}+\frac12\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(x_k,x_{k+1})}\\
&\leq\eta+\frac{k^{1/\rho}}2\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,x_k)}+\frac12\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,x_{k+1})}.
\end{align*}
Note that $1\leq \rho<\infty$, we thus have
$$\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,x_{k+1})}\leq 2\eta+k^{1/\rho}\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,x_k)}\leq 2\eta+k\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,x_k)}.$$
By induction we can easily deduce that
$$\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,x_k)}\leq 2\eta (k+1)!$$

Fix $t\in(0,T)$, then there is some $1\leq k\leq n$ such that $t\in [x_{k-1},x_k)$, so
\begin{align*}
\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,t)}&\leq 2\eta (k+1)!\\
&=2\eta \Gamma(k+2)\\
&=2\eta \Gamma\left(3+\frac{k-1}2\cdot2\right).
\end{align*}
Since $\|f\|_{L^\rho(0,t)}\geq \|f\|_{L^\rho(0,x_{k-1})}=\frac{(k-1)^{1/\rho}}2$, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\|\varphi\|_{L^\gamma(0,t)}&\leq 2\eta\Gamma\left(3+2(2\|f\|_{L^\rho(0,t)})^\rho\right)\\
&\leq\eta\Phi\left(2^\rho\|f\|_{L^\rho(0,t)}^\rho\right).
\end{align*}